# .Net AutomationProperties name for DataGrid item doesn't change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, automation

I'm trying to change the `DataGrid` Item `AutomationProperties` name Item inside `DataGrid`, but it never changes and usually gets the class name as `AutomationProperties` name.

The code in the XAML

```
<DataGrid>             <!-- added by edit -->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextCellStyle}" Header="Name" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextCellStyle}" Header="Value" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgcStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Value, TargetNullValue='No value'}"/>
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Path=Value, TargetNullValue='No value'}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Path=AutomationName}"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see even if I'm using `datagrid.itemcontainerstyle` but still the name would be something like the class path "App.Shared.Models.ItemModel"

Comment: This says override tostring to on the class you have per row. The class name you're seeing. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2015/03/19/giving-your-xaml-element-an-accessible-name-part-3-other-interesting-ways/

Comment: Cool thanks!, solved the issue, but still I don't know y it's not working while trying to bind the same value from a property in the class, do you have any guess about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Andy replied with solved the issue

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2015/03/19/giving-your-xaml-element-an-accessible-name-part-3-other-interesting-ways/

Comment: If you are binding a property to a string value (`AutomationProperties.Name` is of type String), and the value of the property is not a string itself, the binding will call `ToString()` on the value in the property and assign the result to the binding target. The default implementation of `ToString()` returns the name of the type. So any time you see a type name inside of your UI, you know that you are binding a non-string object to a string property. You either need to change the type of the property, override `ToString()`, or use an IValueConverter to handle converting to/from string.